# A problem that lies beyond the eyes

Tags: cipher

> Find the answer,
>   Find the code,
>   Know the truth,
>   Lessen your load ...
>   Closer than you realize,
>   the answer lies,
>   the answer lies,
>   beyond the eyes ...
>
> **YEAIMNHSIAQWERITLLKITTYUIHIEIWI1POOLI1VBCXI:I3MKFAI0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution leads to:

> Matthew 11:30 which depending on translation is "For my yoke is easy and my burden is light."

Because:

> The answer lies beyond the 'eyes' is actually **the letter I**. Giving M A T T H E W 1 1 : 3 0

Like this:

> YEAI **M** NHSI **A** QWERI **T** LLKI **T** TYUI **H** I **E** I **W** I **1** POOLI **1** VBCXI **:** I **3** MKFAI **0**

Comment: "Lessen your load" is a hint at the solution, I assume.

Comment: Well done Hugh Meyers ...viewed 116 times and answered by you!

Comment: now, does anyone care to ponder what Jesus meant when he said that ...considering his yoke, ultimately, was the cross! Not so light ....!?

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate for me to comment on that, I'm not religious in the slightest and I'd rather not offend or upset anyone with my opinions.